# What to look for when searching for HIPAA Hosting Server?

Tags: security, hosting, web-hosting

We are looking to get a HIPAA Hosting server for one of our clients. What should we look for in such server? There are so many hosting providers who are offering the same things. How do I know which one is best?

NOTE: I am NOT looking for hosting recommendation.

Just want to know what we need to look for in HIPAA Hosting servers?

**If a Server Admin can answer this question, that would be great.**

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is a **HIPAA Hosting Server**?

Comment: I'm sure they will happily share any SOC audits/external audits with you.

Answer (score 1):

Your organization (or your client) needs a compliance person, someone who learns the regulations. And a leader in charge of developing and improving an IT security program. Customizing controls to fit the environment, and taking responsibility.

Products are not sufficient to get you compliant. In theory HIPAA as a feature is a good sign, indicates the tools are there, and others may have used them successfully. But the question is not can the software encrypt data on the wire, or report on access logs. The question is do you actually execute those things successfully.

And we at Server Fault are no help, we don't know the organization at all.